# Highstock: how to make series name of first column to be dynamic on tooltip, year wise

Tags: highcharts

[image]I have to display two bars in one chart, where first series (bar) is of year 2015, and second is of year 2016. But when the chart contains data for two years. Then I should need tooltip `{series.name}` to pick `{point.key}` and extract year from it lets says, 2016, then on run time change series.name to 2016 for first bar and second bar to be `{2016 - 1} = 2015` on tooltip. So if data for bars is from 3-4 years, in order for first series, right now it's taking only series.name which I added, but how to make it dynamic for first series year wise that we can easily pick from `{point.key}`. I know highstock isn't meant to work like that, but this kind of trick I'm applying to be able to generate comparative reports for this year vs last year bars.

Note: In order to plot graph on one point, timestamps for both bars will remain same, but values will be from last year to be able to plot two bars together.

So I need to change `Previous Year` to `2010` and `Current Year` to `2011` on tooltip dynamically by picking year from headerText that is `Week from Monday, Aug 9, 2011`.

**JS Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/sfwcqk1w/

Comment: Why not add an extra property to your series that states what year it is for? Do you have a sample of what you want it to look like - it is really hard to tell from your description?

Comment: @wergeld Hey I have added js fiddle, for some reasons it's not displaying content. But same code is working fine on my local system. Any how, you will able to see what actually is happening after checking the code itself or you may be able to execute as well.

I want it to: pick year from tooltip {point.y}, and then replace text Current Year on tooltip with this year and replace Previous year with (picked year - 1) on tooltip. In that way, in whole series tooltip will have dynamic year as per bars, so that it can contain many years data.

Comment: @wergeld I didn't get you on this => 'add an extra property to your series'. Does that mean add one more bar but I don't need that. Or did you mean to pass year with series.data?

Comment: Take a look at the API docs (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cbar%3E.data). You can add another property to a data point like: data: [{
    x: 1,
    y: 1,
    name: "Point2",
    color: "#00FF00",
 extraNote: 'Some Text'
} then you can call it from the tooltip.

Comment: Would that also work with HighStock charts, where x is timstamp and y is value.

Comment: Yes, that would work for any chart. You just have to set your data point as an object instead of an array of x/y. So, `{x: someX, y:someY, note: someNote}` vs `[someX, someY]`.

Comment: I believe this would surely work but do you think there could be a way to modify tooltip directly from {point.y} as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have full control what it is displayed in a tooltip via [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter). You can make your own calculations there. In the tooltip you have access to all points from the series.

Adding additional properties for points with enabled data grouping will not work - in a tooltip you get grouped points - and those points do not have additional properties.

Your tooltip might look like this - it includes some default formatting:

```
formatter: function() {
    var points = this.points;

    var headerFormat = '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + Highcharts.dateFormat('Week from %A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</span><br/>';

    var pointFormat = '',
        previousYear;

    points.forEach(function(point) {
      var name = point.series.name,
        part;

      if (name === 'Previous Year') {
        previousYear = part = new Date(point.x).getFullYear();
      } else if (name === 'Current Year') {
        part = previousYear + 1
      } else {
        part = name;
      }
      pointFormat += '<span style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + part + ': <b>' + point.y + '</b><br/>';
    });

    return headerFormat + pointFormat;
  }
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/sfwcqk1w/3/

Comment: On this same graph, I got a new issue, could you please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542379/highstock-datagrouping-approximation-average-on-timestamp-values